# Merge lines between keywords into one-line comma separated values

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

Between first occurrence of `Cat` to next occurrence of `Cat`, it should create a separate line with delimiter as ",".

File input  as below.

```
Cat
AA
BB
CC
Cat
AA-1
BB-1
CC-1
```

Output expected:

```
Cat,AA,BB,CC
Cat,AA-1,BB-1,CC-1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this with `sed`:

```
sed '1{h;d;};/^Cat$/!{H;$!d;};x;s/\n/,/g;${x;/^Cat$/H;x;}' infile
```

explained:

```
sed '1{                   # if this is the 1st line
h                         # copy over the hold space
d                         # and delete it
}
/^Cat$/!{                 # if the line doesn't match Cat
H                         # append to hold space and
$!d                       # delete it if it's not the last line 
}
x                         # exchange pattern space w. hold buffer
s/\n/,/g                  # replace all newline chars with commas
${                        # check if the last line of input matches Cat:
x                         # exchange pattern space w. hold buffer
/^Cat$/H                  # if the line matches Cat append it to hold buffer
x                         # exchange back
}' infile
```

Comment: +1 Would you care to expand yr solution by describing `sed` cmds and script blocks briefly ? (Not for me ...  I do have access to `info sed` ! ;-).

Answer (score 2):

awk

```
awk '
    /Cat/ {
        if (NR>1) print ""
        printf "%s", $0
        next
    } 
    {printf ",%s", $0} 
    END {print ""}
' file
```

Another version that heavily relies on awk variables: (added before I read your comment about "Cat" needing to be a case-insensitive regex)

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="Cat"; FS="\n"; OFS=","} NR>1 {$1=RS; NF--; print}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed ':a;N;s/\n/,/;ta' file | sed 's/,Cat/\nCAT/g'
```

or

```
tr '\n' ',' < file | sed 's/,Cat/\nCAT/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution does not require to read the whole file into memory. In other words: It will work on a 1 TB file being processed on a 1 GB machine as long as the full lines are less than 1 GB.

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN { $sep = shift; }
          if(/^$sep$/o) { @p and print join(",", @p)."\n"; @p = (); }
          chomp; push @p, $_;
          END { print join(",", $sep, @p)."\n"; }' Cat /tmp/cat
```